# where to find a good instruction how to parse a c++ header file?

Tags: c++, header

where to find a good instruction how to parse a c++ header file?

edit: i want to parse it with haskell, there is a parsec libraray but i need some examples.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Parse how? What purpose? Only keywords or? Do you care about the syntax or not? And so on..

Comment: ISO/IEC 14882:2003 would be a start

Comment: You will basically need to write a full-blown C++ parser, which is a massive task.  Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: C++ is notoriously difficult to parse. If you just need the syntax tree and don't care that much how you got it, you could try using clang's C++ front-end. I'm told its architecture lends itself to this kind of integration into other apps. http://clang.llvm.org/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an existing C++ parser (you're unlikely to ever succeed in writing one yourself that cover all the corner cases of the grammar, it's horrendous).

I can only recommend the [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing C++ is an immense undertaking, so step 1 is to use an established parser that someone else has already written. [boost](http://www.boost.org/).[wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/wave/index.html) is a good place to start.